# Arraylist looping malfunction

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have a `MainList` that has 61 elements and a `subList` of 9 elements.
Out of the 9 elements in `subList`, 8 of them is in `MainList`.

My objective is simply remove those objects that existed in both list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < subList.size();i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < mainList.size();j++){
        if(subList.get(i).equals(mainList.get(j))){
            mainList.remove(j);
            subList.remove(i);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, after the forloop, `subList` still remains 5 elements, meaning the forloop only able to find 4 objects similar.

Afterwards, I wrote another forloop to debug the situation as below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < subList.size();i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < mainList.size();j++){
    if(subList.get(i).equals(mainList.get(j))){
            System.out.println("something");
        }
   }
}
```

And I get to see 4 times of "something". I'm wondering why the first forloop doesnt find all similar objects?

Comment: Don't loop using indices and alter the collection inside the loops, that will most likely result in errors. Use iterators instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgo the loops and use Collection.[removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in
>   the specified collection (optional operation). After this call
>   returns, this collection will contain no elements in common with the
>   specified collection.

Since you want to remove duplicates from both lists you will need to make a copy of one of the lists firsts.

```
List<?> sublistCopy = new ArrayList(sublist);

subList.removeAll(mainList);
mainList.removeAll(sublistCopy);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the [`Collection.removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method:

```
mainList.removeAll( subList );
```

`remove()`'ing from a `List`changes the indices. It is recommended to use an `Iterator` to traverse and remove from collections:

```
for ( Iterator<...> iterator = mainList.iterator() ; iterator.hasNext() ; ) {
    Object o = iterator.next();
    if (subList.contains( o )  ) { iterator.remove(); }
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: i think `mainList.removeAll( subList )` will remove common objects only from the mainList not from subList

Comment: That's true. It's not clear if the OP wants only the main elements removed or a symmetric situation. In any case, it's trivial to extend to the case you describe. The point is that OP should use the built-in methods.

Answer (score 3):

When you remove an element from an ArrayList, the indices of the elements following it are decreased by one, so you should decrement the indices of your loop to account for that.

For example, `subList.remove(3);` will move the element prviously at the index 4 to index 3, so in order for your loop not to skip that element, you should decrement the index of your loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < subList.size();i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < mainList.size();j++){
        if(subList.get(i).equals(mainList.get(j))){
            mainList.remove(j);
            subList.remove(i);
            i--;
            j--; // actually j-- may not be needed, since you break
                 // from the inner loop and start a new inner loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a more elegant option is going backwards, from sublist.size() to 0. Then you would not have to decrease "manually" the indexes

Comment: @Pablo I think using an Iterator's remove method would be even more elegant. Then you don't have to worry about indices at all.

Answer (score 0):

make sure both elements are equal(check if there are some white spaces contains in the list).

```
for(int i=0;i<subList.size();i++){
    if(mainList.contains(subList.get(i)){
          mainList.remove(subList.get(i));  //remove the element from mainList.
          subList.remove(i);   //removes the element from subList.

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify the list concurrently using index. You can use a while loop and an [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

As per the documentation:

Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.